# Rewrite defines as c++

Tags: c++

Hy, it's possible to rewrite this two definitions as c++ code functiom? 
I want to remove #Define

Define 1:

```
#define DO_ALL_BLOCK_IP(iter)   \
    for ((iter) = m_block_ip.begin(); (iter) != m_block_ip.end(); ++(iter))
```

Define2 :

```
#define DO_ALL_BLOCK_EXCEPTION(iter) \
    for ((iter) = m_block_exception.begin(); (iter) != m_block_exception.end(); ++(iter))
```

Comment: How is this *not* C++?

Comment: I mean, as function. I want to remove  #define and rewrite as a function

Comment: Your defines are not complete statements (the body of the `for` loop is missing), so you won't be able to replace them for functions without modifying every call site.

Comment: Do you need to access `iter` inside the loop, or only `*iter`?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/LtyDtJJ7 Here is full file, maybe this Information is userfull.

Answer (score 3):

Not directly - the syntax `DO_ALL_BLOCK_IP(iter) {/* code here */}` is not valid if `DO_ALL_BLOCK_IP` is a function.

You could use the new C++ range for syntax, as long as you don't need to use the iterator directly (only the values):

```
for(auto& value : m_block_ip)
{
    // code here
}
```

If you *must* use a function for some reason, you could pass it a functor, and use a lambda expression to define that:

```
// definition (assuming m_block_ip is a vector of block_ip_t)
void DO_ALL_BLOCK_IP(std::function<void(std::vector<block_ip_t>::iterator)> f) {
    for(auto iter = m_block_ip.begin(); iter != m_block_ip.end(); iter++)
        f(iter);
}

// alternate definition that *may* be more efficient, but also more cumbersome
template<class F_CLASS> void DO_ALL_BLOCK_IP(F_CLASS f) {
    for(auto iter = m_block_ip.begin(); iter != m_block_ip.end(); iter++)
        f(iter);
}

// how to call
DO_ALL_BLOCK_IP([&](std::vector<block_ip_t>::iterator iter) {
    // code here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your macros are basically a prefix for some code that will do something for each iterator in a range. While you can't do *exactly* the same using functions, the function [`std::for_each`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) already pretty much does this; with lambda functions, it can look like this:

```
std::for_each(nums.begin(), nums.end(), 
    [](int &n){ 
        // Doing something with an element of nums
        // and maybe something else
        // In a block that looks pretty much like you would
        // use with your macro.
        // Note that instead of continue, you'd use return, though.
    });
```

Comment: Note that there's no equivalent to `break`. You might need  `std::find` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Since this works on blocks, it's not directly possible to rewrite on functions. You'd need to change every usage, unfortunately.

If `DO_ALL_BLOCK_IP` was a function, this wouldn't compile.

```
DO_ALL_BLOCK_IP(x)
{
    // stuff
}
```

What you can do instead is to just use Standard Library Algorithms or range-for loop (possibly using a lambda).